# Exporting data from Access to Excel (more than 65000 record)

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table in Access, more than 300000 records, and I want to export to Excel, but it seems like I can't export more than 65000 records. I've tried the available option without formatting and layout, but all I get is an empty Excel file. Is there a method to solve the issue?

I'm using Windows XP and MS Office 2007.

Comment: How are you exporting the records?

Comment: Right click on the table > export > excel > etcetera etcetera

Answer (score 1):

The Excel XLS workbook format is limited to 65,536 rows.  Export to XLSX instead, which can accommodate over a million rows.